# Easiest way to change directory into its own logical volume in LVM2

Tags: linux, lvm

I have a dir called /mydir on logical volume /dev/vg1/lv_root ( / )

var is on its own logical volume, so is opt and /usr.. If I have free space in the volume group, what is the easiest way to change /mydir to make /mydir the mountpoint for a new logical volume in the vol group called /dev/vg1/lv_mydir ?  Cent 6 EXT4 file system.

Edit:  I havent created the new logical volume yet.

Answer (score -1):

Just mount your /dev/vg1/lv_mydir to /mydir.

```
mount -t ext4 /dev/vg1/lv_mydir /mydir
```

As Adrian pointed out i assumed a lot, so yes if you have any files residing in current directory you will have to preserve them somewhere and then copy to the new mount. Also on the new LV you will need to create ext4 partition before mounting it.

Comment: You've left out a bunch of steps to the point of misleading the OP. You've left out the creation of the partition. Additionally, if the OP doesn't move the files into the created partition, the empty partition will mask the existing directory's contents and cause the OP to believe that the files are missing.